# How to create a variable that is set based on a text files contents (batch file)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Okay, so I have this bit of code, which writes a few numbers into a text file.

```
echo 1 >> "C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\charlv.txt"
echo 0 >> "C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chardeaths.txt"
echo 0 >> "C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\charexp.txt"
echo 0 >> "C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp1.txt"
echo 0 >> "C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp2.txt"
echo 0 >> "C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp3.txt"
```

Now, what I want to do is create variables based on what was written in those text file. My reasoning for this is to create a save file, so that once the program is closed, the variables that are necessary will be able to come back.

I have this bit of code, which I thought would work, that is supposed to set a variable based on what is inside of the text files, but it only sets the variables to "0", even "LV" which is supposed to be set to "1".

```
set /a "LV=C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\charlv.txt"
set /a "DEATHS=C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chardeaths.txt"
set /a "EXP=C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\charexp.txt"
set /a "EQP1=C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp1.txt"
set /a "EQP2=C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp2.txt"
set /a "EQP3=C:\Users\Slots\Slot1\chareqp3.txt"
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my last bit of code?

Answer (score 2):

`set /a` is attempting to evaluate the filename, which makes no sense.

```
set/p var=<filename
```

may work for you.

Since this appears to be a game, I'd suggest

- declare all of your savable variables starting with the same character-sequence, such as `#`

Then, your `game save` command is simply

```
set #>filename
```

and your `game reload` routine is

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in ('set # 2^>nul') do set "%%a="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filename) do set "%%a"
```

The first line clears the current game variables, the second reloads from the file.

Comment: Thank you for this, but it doesn't quite click with me, I'm unfamiliar with the 
 use of the command "for", I also have no clue what "tokens" are, however I have seen both used in A LOT of programs, do you mind linking me somewhere that can explain it, or give me a briefing here?

Comment: From the prompt, use `for /?` for documentation (*command* /? will generally produce documentation = you many need to append `|more` to stop it scolling off)